What material might a blender's "rubber" seals be?
What material might a blender's "rubber" seals be?
I thought, what if I could buy it in bulk and cut my own, rather than pay 5 euros for a small circle of it.

You might try a food-grade silicone sheet, such as is used for baking molds or cookie sheets. However, 1. it might not be much less expensive. 2. You'd need the same thickness to seal effectively. 3. How is it held in place?

https://www.alliedmetrics.com/food-grade-o-rings-and-seals-materials-selection-guide/
